# Add 'page template' column to dashboard for CPTs

Tags: custom-post-types, admin

How can I add a 'Page Template' column to the Dashboard, so that viewing 'All cpt_name' shows which template is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// add new column to the columns array
function wpse267793_columns($columns) {
    // Column name
    $columns['template'] = 'Template file';
    return $columns;
}

function wpse267793_show_template_columns($name, $post_id) {
    // get template file name from post meta
    $template = get_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', true);
    echo $template;
}

// change 'CPT' to the relevant custom post type
add_filter('manage_CPT_posts_columns', 'wpse267793_columns');

add_action('manage_CPT_posts_custom_column',  'wpse267793_show_template_columns', 10, 2);
```

- [manage_posts_custom_column](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column)
- [manage_posts_columns](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_posts_columns)

Comment: @ Max Yudin ... Thanks. I delayed responding because adding this column also adds the template info to an additional column I'd added previously to show post ID, and I wanted to try to find a fix before posting here - but haven't yet been able to do so.

Comment: So, what's the question if you can add a column by yourself?

Comment: @ Max Yudin ... I didn't know about _wp_page_template.

Comment: And, likely, you were banned by Google.

Comment: @ Max Yudin ... if you don't know what to search for, it's difficult to find answers. And, as always, I searched before posting here.